# CORS Problem. I need help to solve this issue

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cors

I have Problem with cors, I did almost every possible way to fix but couldn't achieve.
Here is my [image] code.

This is my request from react app

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My cors is working so I hope this helps.

You can remove your middleware (`express.use(cors({}))`) on what I assume is your index.js / app.js , then go to your auth route file and require the the cors module in it.

In your request use the cors variable as middleware:

```
router.get('/', cors(YOUR_CORS_OPTIONS_OBJECT), async (req, res) => {
   // functionality
})
```

I've attached screenshots of my index.js as well as my route that contains cors.

index.js:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2FEr.png

route:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVfmg.png

Just take note that if you do it this way, that you'll have to add it in as middleware in each request route.

Comment: I think it is a problem with making a GET request from axios, Direct Link is working when make http request it's showing this problem again and again